# Получить user_id по имея только username в телеграм / get user id by user name

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, telethon, pyrogram

Мне с сайта на Тильде в телеграм прилетает оповещение, когда заполняют форму. В тексте оповещения есть ник в телеграм.
Я могу вытащить из текста ник.
Подскажите, что написать в тот же pyrogram или aiogram, чтобы он поискал по нику и нашёл user_id, чтоб я мог от своего имени потом человеку отправить ссылку-приглашение?

п.с. Да, можно на сайт в форму вставить ссылку на телеграм-бота, чтоб не морочиться с этим. Но нельзя так сделать, требования чтоб просто ник оставляли. Не по христиански это, заставлять людей с сайта в телегу и обратно бегать))

Comment: авторизуйте пользователя через телеграм. да и не у всех есть юзернеймы